# How to use RAII appropriately/reduce memory leaks in this situation

Tags: c++, opengl, renderer

I'm not sure how I can use RAII to my fullest in the situation that I have. This is the situation:

I am creating a basic renderer. Geometry is described by a Geometry class, which may have vertices added to it. In order for Geometry objects to be used for rendering, it must first be compiled (i.e. a VBO will be created for the Geometry). Compiliation (and decompiliation) of geometery objects is done via a Renderer object, decompilation must be done once you are done with geometery objects. If decompilation is not done, there will be memory leaks.

Here is an example of what I'm describing:

```
Renderer renderer; // the renderer object

{
    Geometry geometry;

    // add vertices
    // and play around with material, etc.

    if(!renderer.compile(geometery); // compile the geometery, so we can use it
    {
        cerr << "Failed to compile geometry!\n";
    }

    // now we can use it...
    renderer.render(geometry, RenderType::TriangleStrips);

} // if I don't call renderer.decompile(geometry) here, I will get a leak
```

What I'm trying to do is decompile my geometery, without explicitly telling the renderer to decompile it. This is to simply reduce memory leaks. My first thought was to use RAII, but if I do so the Geometry class would require the Renderer class, which seems quite messy. As I would require a reference to the Renderer object which compiled the geometery.

Another alternative I thought of was to make the renderer create geometry, but this will cause geometry objects to allocated dynamically (i.e. with new), and it also seems quite messy.

I also thought of placing a handle object within the geometery, such as a unique_ptr to an abstract handle object.

e.g.

```
class GeometeryHandle
{
   virtual ~GeometeryHandle() = 0; 
};
```

Which might actually work, as it may also be used to store the `GLuint` within the handle. I am unsure if this is appropriate though, as I could simply decompile the geometry directly via a Renderer reference. i.e. it will do the same thing if I call it directly through the destructor.

How should I design this appropriately so I don't accidentally not decompile geometry?

Comment: "decompile" usually means taking compiled code, and from it, generating the original high-level source code that it was compiled from (or something as closed to that as possible). It does *not* mean "free the memory/resources used by the compiled object", which is what you seem to use the term to mean. You might avoid a lot of confusion by renaming it. :)

Comment: @jalf In the 3d domain, "compile" / "decompile" are related to transformations to the geometry, for example packing it / optimizing it for better performances...

Comment: @Synxis: I have never heard "decompile" used in this domain. And the only place I've heard "compile" used like this is for either display lists or that Godawful compiled-vertex-array extension.

Comment: @Synxis: but the OP clearly talks about "decompiling" as a means to release memory. And both meanings of the word are about creating a transformation of input data (whether the data is a geometry mesh or source code), not about releasing data that is no longer used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear who is supposed to be responsible for what in your design. That's step 1 in figuring out how to employ any form of resource management: deciding who's responsible for what.

For example, you say that "Geometry is described by a Geometry class, which may have vertices added to it." OK, but how does this relate to the post-compilation data? If the user adds vertices to `Geometry` after it's compiled, do those vertices automatically get placed in the compiled data? Or is the compiled data completely separate from the `Geometry` class after compiling it, such that changes to the `Geometry` class don't update the compiled data?

It sounds to me like you're conflating two very different ideas: `GeometryBuilder` and `Renderable`. `GeometryBuilder` is what you put vertex data into. Then you take that and create a `Renderable` out of it. The `Renderable` is an optimized form of the data stored in a `GeometryBuilder`. The object is completely independent of the `GeometryBuilder` that created it. The `Renderable` is what you can actually render with.

So you would do this:

```
GeometryBuilder meshBuilder;

meshBuilder.AddVertex(...);
...

Renderable renderMesh = render.CreateRenderable(meshBuilder);
```

After this point, `meshBuilder` is independent of `renderMesh`. You can delete one and the other's fine. You can "compile" `renderMesh` multiple times and get identical copies of the same data. And so forth.

Comment: Seems that this would work, however it seems quite close to the 2nd thing I mentioned. In this case "GeometeryBuilder" seems that it should just be an array of vertices, unless I see a reason to make it a seperate class. It still seems quite messy, as Renderable will have to be allocated on the heap, will it not? Unless I return by value... Hm thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @miguel.martin: Well it's hard to suggest something when you don't really explain what these classes store or what they're doing. You don't say why you need to "compile" `Geometry` objects to begin with. Also, `GeometryBuilder` would "just be an array of vertices", but it would also be responsible for formatting them and allowing other various transforms that you might be interested in. So it's not merely a vector. Lastly, heap allocation is not evil; it's not something to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I did actually mention why I need to compile Geometry objects, "In order for Geometry objects to be used for rendering, it must first be compiled (i.e. a VBO will be created for the Geometry)". The heap allocations just seemed unnecessary, IMO.

Comment: @miguel.martin: That explains *what* you did, not *why* you did it. My question is, why do you need an explicit "compile" step? Isn't that something that should happen when you build the Geometry object? And if not, *why* not?

Comment: As compiling a geometry object each time you add a vertex to it clearly wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: @miguel.martin: And that goes back to my point about wanting two separate objects. You have one object that has two responsibilities: it holds the pre-"compiled" data and the post-"compiled" data. It's best to have objects that don't have two responsibilities like this. That way, people won't modify a vertex in the geometry class and then wonder why it's not showing up properly in the rendered scene. If it's two objects, it's immediately clear that the holder of the pre-"compiled" data is just a factory object for the post-"compiled" object.

Comment: @miguel.martin: This is also the source of your basic RAII problem: if it's two objects, with two independent lifetimes, then both of them can be proper, independent RAII objects.

Comment: I see, that would probably be the best way to go about this. This is so complicated. The only problem is... the renderer would have to maintain compiled geometry and be able to render them. Unless I split compilation of geometry to another class.

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1:

You can use a helper class:

```
class CompileHandler
{
    private:
        Geometry& g;
        Renderer& r;
    public:
        CompileHandler(Geometry& _g, Renderer& _r) : g(_g), r(_r) 
        {
        }
        ~CompileHandler()
        {
            r.decompile(g);
        }
};
```

And you can use it the following way:

```
{
    Geometry geometry;
    CompileHandler ch(geometry,renderer);

    // add vertices
    // and play around with material, etc.

    if(!renderer.compile(geometery); // compile the geometery, so we can use it
    {
        cerr << "Failed to compile geometry!\n";
    }

    // now we can use it...
    renderer.render(geometry, RenderType::TriangleStrips);
// decompilation is automatic on destruction of the CompileHandler object
}
```

### Method 2:

Create a more robust hierarchy:

```
GeometryCompiler
   ^
   |
   | inherits
   |
Renderer
```

On compilation of the geometry, the geometry compiler (here, the renderer) notify the geometry that it has been compiled (and set a `GeometryCompiler` pointer inside the geometry to it, the compiler).
Then, on destruction of the geometry, if the pointer is not null, it can require the `GeometryCompiler` to decompile it.

Comment: hm, thanks for the suggestion. I'll consider my options and try to implement a good way to do things.

Comment: I personnally like the second method, because it is not specific to rendering - you can use the pattern for other applications.

Comment: what would I use this for other than rendering? S:

Answer (score 0):

RAII requires the "undo" operations to be played by dstructors.

In you case, the geometry is destroyed, but the render survive. The only trigger you have is the Geometry destructor, that should know what render compiled, to call him to decompile.

But since is not in the purpose of geometry to know about rederes, you most likely need an helper class (let's call it `Compile_guard`) that should be instantiated just after the geometry completion, taking a Geometry and Render as parameters, and calling Render::compile upon construction and Render::decompile upon destruction:

```
Renderer renderer; // the renderer object

{
    Geometry geometry;

    // add vertices
    // and play around with material, etc.

    Compile_guard guard(render, geometry);

    if(!guard); // Invalid compilation ....
    { 
        cerr << "Failed to compile geometry!\n";
        return; // this is exception safe!
    }

    // now we can use it...
    renderer.render(geometry, RenderType::TriangleStrips);

} //here guard will decompile
```

About the Compile_guard, it can be something like

```
class Compile_guard
{
public:
   Compile_guard(Render& r, Geometry& g) :render(&r), geometry(&g), good(false)
   { good = render->compile(*geometry); }

   ~Compile_guard()
   { if(good) render->decompile(*geometry); }

   explicit operator bool() const { return good; }

   Compile_guard(const Compile_guard&) =delete;  //just avoid copy and assign.
   Compile_guard& operator=(const Compile_guard&) =delete;
private:
   Render* render;
   Geometry* geometry;
   bool good;
};
```